# Android Studio (Intellij) debugging: how to see the right return statement?

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea

While debugging an Android app, I frequently encounter a situation like this:[image]

The debug information shown is incorrect, misleading:

1. Despite the line being highlighted, the 2nd return statement is not reached - no ParseException is thrown (e is null)
2. The input value shown at this time is incorrect - it's the function's return value. Input value is shown correctly just a step before this.

Is there a fix for this behavior?

Comment: I've ran into similar kind of debugging madness. I just circumvented the problem by using something along the lines of `Log.d(TAG,"Exception thrown` or `No exception with input: "+input)` before the return statements to get proper values out to LogCat.